# Blazor - contextual buttons in parent component changed by child component

Tags: data-binding, blazor

I'm hoping someone can help as I'm new to Blazor.

I've started a new Blazor project and am trying to add contextual buttons in the top bar that can be changed by / based on the child component (when you navigate to page 1 it can show different things to when you navigate to page 2)

[image]

This is my approach so far:

**TopBar.razor** - *A template for the top bar with render fragment so I can render different stuff*

```
@inject Learning.Data.TopBarContext TopBarContext

<div class="col-sm-6">@Context</div>
<span class="col-sm-2">@Text1</span>
<span class="col-sm-2">@Text2</span>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    private RenderFragment Context { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text1 { get; set; } = "Not Set";

    [Parameter]
    public string Text2 { get; set; } = "Not Set";    
}
```

**MainLayout.razor** - *I use TopBar and cascade it down to all the pages*

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <TopBar />
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="TopBar" Name="TopBar">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>        
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private TopBar TopBar;
}
```

Now I have to two page components:

**Page1.razor** - *When navigated to will render 3 buttons in top bar*

```
@page "/page1"

<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>

@code {

}
```

**Page2.razor** - *When navigated to will render 2 buttons in top bar*

```
@page "/page2"

<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>

@code {

}
```

I know I can use the code below to pick up the cascaded value:

```
[CascadingParameter(Name = "TopBar")]
    protected string TopBar { get; set; }
```

But not sure how to proceed, I was hoping for something like cascading the whole component down so that in page1 I could do something flexible like:

```
<TopBar>
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
    <button>Three</button>
</TopBar>
```

I may be going about this completely the wrong way (I did think creating a registered singleton might be a way to do it) but any clarification you could offer on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have above, you are almost there. You can cascade the `TopBar` like you have it in your MainLayout, but the code section where you are picking it up is what is throwing you off. You have the cascaded value shown as a string property, but remember that Blazor components are *classes* that are compiled, so you need to list it as a class instead:

```cs
[CascadingParameter]
public TopBar Bar { get; set; }
```

That is how you will capture it in your components, and then you can access the public properties and methods to update them, using code like `Bar.Context = // render fragment of your choice`

This might get a bit tricky though as what you feed to the `Context` property could prove to be painful to build up, so it might be better to have your `TopBar` component render something itself based on a data structure that it holds instead. I've done something with a Dictionary before for links that worked well, so in your `TopBar` you would have a private property:

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> LinkBodiesAndRefs { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

This stored link text as the key and the target URL as the value for each record, 
and then to render them, something like the following:

**TopBar.razor**

```cs
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in LinkBodiesAndRefs)
{
    <a href="@entry.Value">@entry.Key</a>
}
```

Then in the @code block of the TopBar, I added a few methods to interact with the dictionary:

**TopBar.razor (continued)**

```cs
@code {

    private Dictionary<string, string> LinkBodiesAndRefs { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void AddLink(string linkBody, string linkDestination)
    {
        LinkBodiesAndRefs.Add(linkBody, linkDestination);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void RemoveLink(string linkBody)
    {
        LinkBodiesAndRefs.Remove(linkBody);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        LinkBodiesAndRefs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in your component that captures the cascaded `TopBar`, just use the methods to interact with the data structure as you would expect, whether it be a list or dictionary or whatever:

```cs
Bar.AddLink("Products", "/products");

Bar.RemoveLink("Products");
```

The same approach could be used with lists of objects if they need further interaction, and those could even be Razor Components and you could have a list of `RenderFragment` in your TopBar that gets rendered out if you wanted. The point is that the `CascadingValue` can provide a class that you can then define the interactivity with, and you can get up to all sorts of shenanigans to make cool things happen.

Hope this helps, and I don't have my IDE handy at the moment so there may be some syntax to work out that I missed in the above examples. Sorry in advance if that's the case.